# Подключение промежуточного слоя

Tags: django

Странная ошибка появляется. Добавил слой в MIDDLEWARE и вот пишет
WSGI application 'project.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
В настройках установлено
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'
Где ошибка-то?

Comment: Когда вы в питоне делаете `from project.wsgi import application` в папке с проектом, оно работает?

Comment: не понял, что нужно сделать?